# Floating Div Crosshairs - Confine To Div

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a crosshair-style cursor effect to a div that contains a [D3 Datamap](http://datamaps.github.io/). I've got it working using jQuery but the crosshairs seem to overlap their parent div on the bottom and right, but not the top and left.

I've created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TomPlum/9r4rtcz9/3/) to demonstrate.

I've tried changing the `position` property of the crosshair div to no avail.

On my page, changing `position` to `absolute` seems to correctly confine the crosshairs to the container, but the center point is offset from the cursor (`e.pageX, e.pageY`). However, I cannot recreate this in the fiddle, as `fixed, static, relative, absolute` make no difference.

One solution I've found is to set the `width` and `height` properties of the container and hairs to fixed values. However, I need the container to be responsive.

Answer (score 3):

First, the `vertical` and `horizontal` lines also overlapping the box on the top and left, it was not visible because of the body-viewport ;).

Second, I did some investigation and found out that the best solution would be to place the `crosshair-lines` inside the map-container which are positioned absolute to the `map-container`. Therefore we have better control of the position and behavior of the `crosshair-lines` and the `map-container` can be flexible aswell!

I added the default cursor for better testing. — https://jsfiddle.net/9r4rtcz9/6/ – code snippet below

```js
//Map Hover Crosshairs
$(function() {
  var cH = $('#crosshair-h'),
    cV = $('#crosshair-v');
  $('.map_wrapper').on('mouseover', function() {
    cH.css('visibility', 'visible');
    cV.css('visibility', 'visible');

    $('.map_wrapper').bind('mousemove', function(e) {
      cH.css('top', e.pageY);
      cV.css('left', e.pageX);
    });
  });

  $('.map_wrapper').on('mouseout', function() {
    cH.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    cV.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.map_wrapper').unbind("mousemove");
  });
});
```

```css
.map_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: default;
}

.hair {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#crosshair-h {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  visibility: visible;
}

#crosshair-v {
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map_wrapper">
  <div class="hair" id="crosshair-h"></div>
  <div class="hair" id="crosshair-v"></div>
</div>

<p class="datamaps">D3 Data Maps Here</p>
```

Comment: When I change the datamap container to `position: relative` and the hair class to `position: absolute`, the crosshairs correctly contain themselves within the div but they are offset from the cursor position. **edit:** I'll try and find a hosted copy of datamaps.min.js so I can try and re-create the problem in a fiddle.

Comment: Okay so the datamap doesn't seem to want to render in the fiddle, but the effect has somewhat been reproduced (the offset isn't as great). https://jsfiddle.net/TomPlum/9r4rtcz9/9/

Comment: remove the margin, increase the negative margin for the .hair, looks good for me https://jsfiddle.net/9r4rtcz9/10/

Comment: Setting the negative padding fixes it for the current size, but once the window is resized, the cursor is offset again. I've managed to get the map rendering now. http://jsfiddle.net/TomPlum/5wnu78d8/2/

Comment: there you go, added transform for the hairs, better then margin, if this is fine for you I will update my answer :) http://jsfiddle.net/5wnu78d8/3/

Comment: It appears to work in the fiddle, even when I resize the container. Why is that? The divs are being translated by a flat value? After a lot of playing about, it still doesn't work on my page, the only difference is that the map container is nested inside a bootstrap column and row.